# How do I add a song to a playlist on an iPod Device (running iOS4)?

Tags: ipod, ipod-touch, ios

It seems like this should be simple, but I can't seem to find the right place to click.

I see how I can go into edit mode for a playlist and remove songs. I just can't figure out how to add songs to a playlist on the device. Ideally I'd like to be able to do it from the now-playing screen somehow, but any solution is acceptable as long as it doesn't involve connecting to my computer and using iTunes to do the add.

Answer (score 3):

On the device, in the tab bar, select Playlists, then select the playlist you want to edit. Press the Edit button, then in the top right corner is a plus sign. Tap the plus sign to add tracks to a playlist on your iOS4 device.

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something obvious. I just didn't see that button. Thanks. BTW: Do you know a way to add the current song to a playlist while you are playing it?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to do that. . . which is actually why I love(d) my Zune so much (RIP) lol

Comment: Can you please scale that screenshot down? It's huge

Comment: You didn't have to remove it completely - all you had to do to scale it 50% was to do `<img src="http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f363bc33a4.png" height="480">`

Comment: lol yeah my bad. i took the long route. i just removed the huge one and scaled the image itself down. still don't get the hang of adding pics on here yet

Comment: I recently figured out how to do this...it seems like there should be a less-complicated way.  Old iPods used to have On-The-Go, which could be created by long-pressing on songs.  Too bad that doesn't work anymore.